# Two version of the same code returns different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

The two code below look same but they give me different result in IE8. Do you have any idea about that?

```
$('#frameMain').load(function(){                                
    var bodyHeight = $(this.contentDocument).find('body').attr('scrollHeight');                
    var bodyHeight2 = document.getElementById('frameMain').document.body.scrollHeight;
});
```

Comment: Good work drachenstern (I have seen similar comments to other questions too). The community appreciates it :)

Comment: Hi @drachenstern. If you notice that my questions are about general thing and don't needs excat answers. Because of it I didn't mark one of them true. But I didn't think that it would be a problem. Thanks for your notify, I'll check my questions and try to check them answered.

Comment: Hi @mavera ~ We tend to appreciate questions that have definite answers on SO. If you can identify some that don't seem to need an answer if you'll comment on those and then someone can take a look and either help you clean them up or they can delete them for you. I'ld be more than happy to discuss this in real-time if you like http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general

Comment: If you could supply a complete example, like an URL I could do some more tests, othervise I have to construct a test to see what is happeninbg. Also Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I see that, these codes are refer to different elements. I'm closing the question. Thanks for your respone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code refer to parent body, not child.

```
document.getElementById('frameMain').document.body.scrollHeight
```

It should be like this:

```
document.getElementById('frameMain').contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself.